# Canvas - Elements overlaying

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I need to build some canvas app, but the shapes are irregular and elements are overlapping each other. I am using **fabric.js** for canvas and importing SVG files to draw elements, but I can't detect right hovered objects.

**Here are examples:**

I want to detect on mouse over when it will be above shape.

[image: Sketch 1]

How it is actualy on my canvas (the red line corners are invisible in canvas ofc)

[image: Sketch 2]

[Example code from Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/hovering/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the "perPixelTargetFind" property of fabricjs.

This will check the mouse over the object with accuracy.
If there is graphic it will trigger the target, otherwise not.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.perPixelTargetFind = true;
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: 'green', top: 50, left: 100 }));
canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: 'green', top: 100, left: 200 }));
  
canvas.on('mouse:over', function(e) {
  e.target.setFill('red');
  canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:out', function(e) {
  e.target.setFill('green');
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width="550" height="550" style="border:#000 1px solid;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, well I spent 5h looking for someting like this :(